# WPF applications hang when usage of DirectInput devices added

Tags: wpf, directx

I used to add Joysticks to my WinForms applications using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device class. Now I want to do the same thing with WPF.

Here is a very simple code sample that I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Interop;

using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput;

namespace JoysticksTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // HANGS WHEN ENTERING DetectInstalledDevices METHOD!!!
            DetectInstalledDevices();
        }

        private void DetectInstalledDevices()
        {
            // Find all the GameControl devices that are attached.
            DeviceList gameControllerList = Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly);

            // check that we have at least one device.
            if (gameControllerList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameControllerList.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Move to the first device
                    gameControllerList.MoveNext();

                    DeviceInstance deviceInstance = (DeviceInstance)gameControllerList.Current;

                    if (deviceInstance.DeviceType == DeviceType.Joystick)
                    {
                        // Some code here   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my WPF application just hangs.

What am I doing wrong? I have Windows 8.1 OS installed on my computer.

Is it WPF or wrong version of Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll?

Comment: Can you Debug and find the Line where it Hangs? is it Manager.GetDevices() which never returns?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava : I added comment right next to the line where it hangs (HANGS WHEN ENTERING DetectInstalledDevices METHOD!!!)

Comment: Ok. Thats just your own method call. Can you step-in or put breakpoints inside that method & check where inside that method? I am pretty sure it would be Manager.GetDevices.

Comment: Mine too happens the same thing, with WinForms and with WPF too.. have you found any solution?